# Triger event whenever remaining time equals X

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a js countdown which is working. I also have the countdown flashing when remaining time gets low.

I want to generate a set of key numbers (for when to flash)

I have this

```js
currenttime = Date.now() / 1000 | 0
targettime = currenttime + 20
flashfrequency = 3
flashenable = 10
setInterval(function() {
  currenttime = Date.now() / 1000 | 0
  remainingtime = targettime - currenttime
  if (remainingtime < 0)
    remainingtime = 0
  if ((remainingtime % flashfrequency === 0) && (remainingtime < flashenable))
    flash = "body {background-color:black; color:white;}"

  else
    flash = "body {background-color:white; color:black;}"

  document.getElementById('timehere').innerHTML = remainingtime;
  document.getElementById('flashhere').innerHTML = flash;

}, 50);
```

```html
<head>
  <style id="flashhere" type="text/css"></style>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="timehere">hello</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

I want to use

```
var flashfrequency=10 //as time when to flash
```

and

```
var flashenable=40 //as maximum remaining time to flash
```

I do not know where to start to generate values from flashfrequency and flashenable

code to generate list of every flashfrequency'th number from 0 thru (0,10,20...) flashenable (...30,40).

if statement to compare remaining time with generated list (0,10,20,30,40)

Comment: Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 Snippet made, and changed flash vars to match snippet example

Comment: `js` at stacksnippets not return expected result ? What is requirement ?

Comment: attempting to get more usability out of this it isnt practical to write if ((remainingtime = 0) || (remainingtime = 10) || (remaini.............(remainingtime = 590) || (remainingtime = 600))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting [% Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

```
if (remainingtime % 10 === 0)
```

for `||` `OR` operator

```
if ((remainingtime == 0) 
    || (remainingtime == 10) 
    || (remainingtime == 20) 
    || (remainingtime == 30) 
    || (remainingtime == 40))
```

at `if` condition

```js
currenttime = Date.now() / 1000 | 0
targettime = currenttime + 50

setInterval(function() {
  currenttime = Date.now() / 1000 | 0
  remainingtime = targettime - currenttime
  if (remainingtime < 0)
    remainingtime=0
  if (remainingtime % 10 === 0)
    flash = "body {background-color:black; color:white;}"

  else
    flash = "body {background-color:white; color:black;}"

  document.getElementById('timehere').innerHTML = remainingtime;
  document.getElementById('flashhere').innerHTML = flash;

}, 50);
```

```html
<head>
  <style id="flashhere" type="text/css"></style>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="timehere">hello</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks combined with '&& remainingtime < flashenable' worked the treat